# A condition for one domain to be included in another domain?

Tags: geometry, built-in-symbols, intersection

Consider two domains:

```
domain1 = Rectangle[{-2.5, -2.5}, {2.5, 2.5}];
domain2[R_] := Disk[{0, 0}, R]
```

I would like to check whether the second domain is completely included in the first domain. My attempt is

```
condition[R_] := If[domain2[R] \[Element] domain1, 1, 0]
condition[1]
```

However, it does not work, as the commands used are incorrect. Could you please tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
domain1 = Rectangle[{-2.5, -2.5}, {2.5, 2.5}];
domain2[R_] := Disk[{0, 0}, R]
```

You can use [`RegionWithin`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionWithin.html):

```
ClearAll[condition]
condition[R_] := Boole @ RegionWithin[domain1, domain2[R]]

{condition[1], condition[3]}
```

> ```
> {1, 0}
> ```

You can also use a combination of `ForAll` and `Resolve`:

```
ClearAll[conditionB]
conditionB[R_] := Resolve[ForAll[x, Implies[x ∈ domain2[R], x ∈ domain1]], Reals]

{conditionB[1], conditionB[2], conditionB[3]}
```

> ```
>  {True, True, False}
> ```

```
ClearAll[conditionC]
conditionC[R_] := Resolve[ForAll[x, ! x ∈ domain2[R] || x ∈ domain1], Reals]

{conditionC[1], conditionC[2], conditionC[3]}
```

> ```
> {True, True, False}
> ```

Answer (score 4):

```
domain1 = Rectangle[{-2.5, -2.5}, {2.5, 2.5}];
domain2[R_] := Disk[{0, 0}, R]
Table[RegionEqual[RegionIntersection[domain1, domain2[R]], 
  domain2[R]], {R, {1, 2, 3}}]
```

> `{True, True, False}`