# A condition for the given point to be included in the domain?

Tags: geometry, built-in-symbols

If we have two domains, [it is possible](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/241461/a-condition-for-one-domain-to-be-included-in-another-domain) to check whether one domain is inside another domain:

```
domain1 = Rectangle[{-2.5, -2.5}, {2.5, 2.5}];
domain2[R_] := Disk[{0, 0}, R]
condition[R_] := Boole @ RegionWithin[domain1, domain2[R]]
```

Now, let us consider a point

```
point[x_,y_] = {x,y}
```

Is it possible to check whether the point belongs to the region using something like RegionWithin (like PointWithin (?))?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
RegionMember[domain1, {1, 1}]
(*True*)
```

Answer (score 4):

For a point, we can also use `RegionWithin` since we can consider the region `Disk[{x0,y0},0]`

```
domain1 = Rectangle[{-2.5, -2.5}, {2.5, 2.5}];
RegionWithin[domain1, Disk[{1, 1}, 0]]
```

> `True`